# DownloadManager names, re-downloaded files

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I use DownloadManager for downloading files and take their names from DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI. Downloading the same file more than 11 times. After 11 times start to wonder strange names. Example:

text.txt

text-1.txt

text-2.txt

text-3.txt

text-4.txt

text-5.txt

text-6.txt

text-7.txt

text-8.txt

text-9.txt

text-10.txt

text-26.txt

text-14.txt

What could be the problem?

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Bring my code

```
public static long downloadFile(Context ctx, String url, String title, String description, String filename, String mimetype, BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete) {
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).mkdirs();
        long res = dm.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url)).setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI).setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle(title).setMimeType(mimetype).setDescription(description).setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename));
        ctx.registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        Toster.showGreenToast(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.download_started, filename));
        return res;
    }

    public static String getDownloadCompletedFileName(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        String res = "";

        try {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

            DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
            q.setFilterById(extras.getLong(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID));
            Cursor c = dm.query(q);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    // process download
                    res = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                    // get other required data by changing the constant passed to getColumnIndex
                }
            }

            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't told us how you're generating the filename in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS

As it says there: the download manager will not overwrite an existing file

As I see it, instead of throwing an exception it will just append a "-n" to the end of the file name.

Comment: My question is "Why after the tenth file download it append "-[random number]" "

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()`, `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` or `setDestinationUri()` when create the [DownloadManager.Request](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html) to set the filename and directory.

Comment: Tried all variants. The same effect